# Bootstrap disable media query showing mobile menu

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

There are other posts about this but nothing helps/works and the section of removing responsiveness in Bootstrap isn't what I want to do. I want to completely KILL, DISABLE by overwriting the media queries that show the button and mobile vertical menu. 
[image: Horizontal menu disappears]

You can view the source on live pages [Here](http://triplewww.com/cm/bs/)

If I remove this button tag:

```
       <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data- target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
```

Then the button and the vertical menu are gone but so is the horizontal menu. What's the exact media query(s) needed to kill this button and menu but retain the horizontal one.

Comment: Could we see all the code of your navbar and whatever custom css is being applied? And a live fiddle would be handy

Answer (score 2):

From [Bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default):

> Change the point at which your navbar switches between collapsed and horizontal mode. Customize the **@grid-float-breakpoint** variable or add your own media query.

Comment: @grid-float-breakpoint is a LESS variable, you can't use it in plain CSS nor in SASS

Comment: You can find **@grid-float-breakpoint** and other bootstrap variables [here](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/).

Comment: Not helpful I'm looking for a solution not documentation.

Answer (score 0):

No need to go disabling media queries.

There should be a subsequent div with an id of `bs-example-navbar-collapse-1`. This div should also have a class `collapse`. Remove this class.

Assuming you aren't compiling with less or sass.

Comment: BTW, the "843px x 520px" has nothing to do with media queries. That is telling you the size of your window.

Comment: No not compiling. Removing id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" does not help it simply removes the menu but not the button and doesn't restore the horizontal menu.  BTW when I resize my browser the button appears at 843 width for some reason. Yes I know it's displaying the size of the window.

Comment: Remove the class "collapse". And remove the button code which you posted as well.

Comment: IF I do that then the horizontal menu is gone.

Comment: Don't remove the whole div, just remove the class attribute from the tag.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to guess because you haven't shown the whole code for your navbar or any css. My best advice is to look at this example: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron-narrow/ and change your code accordingly.